# VBA to sum payments for a specific person and set the sum in a merged cell

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I have a very large excel file, around 50K rows. In Column (C) I have the person numbers 1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,.... and in Column(N) I have the payments for this person, so the data looks like

What I want is to sum All payments for one person from column N and set the result in column O, then merge column O.

[image: excel screenshot]

Comment: You need to provide more detail. So person A has a number of 1, and could appear on multiple rows with multiple payment records.

Do you want to add a total record to each row related to the customer in column O, or is column O some kind of summary area separate to the main table?

What do you mean by merge column O?

I cant help without more info I am afraid.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @smackenzie, for each person all the payments are together, so it can't be separated, now for one person, lets say that he has 10 payment records, I want to sum all his payments, the merge cells O1:O10 and set the result in it.

Comment: @MohammadAwniAli Why not just use the Data/Subtotals method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub summAndMerge()
lastrow = Worksheets("A").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value And Cells(i, 1).Value <>     Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
     intUpper = i
     Debug.Print ("<> -1 and <> +1 " & intUpper)
End If

If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value And Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
     intUpper = i
     Debug.Print ("<> -1 and = +1 " & intUpper & " UPPPER LIMIT")
End If


If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 1).Value And Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      Debug.Print ("<> +1 and = -1:" & i & "LOWER LIMIT")
       Range(Cells(intUpper, 3), Cells(i, 3)).Merge
        Cells(intUpper, 3).Value = "=sumif(B" & CStr(intUpper) & ":B" & CStr(i) & ","">0"")"
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 24)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
End If

If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 1).Value And Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
     Debug.Print ("One Cells: " & i)
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 24)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
      Cells(intUpper, 3).Value = Cells(intUpper, 2).Value
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for the built-in excel `SUMIF` function

```
=sumif(C:C,"specific person number",N:N)
```

Comment: here is the code I am using, it works like a charm for multi record persons, but for one record person, it still has problems, I am working since 36 hours without sleep, so I am unable to know where is the problem!

Comment: 'code' If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            intUpper = i
        End If
    End If
         
Next i

End Sub

  Else
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            intUpper = i
        End If
    End If
         
Next i

Comment: First, go get some sleep :-). Second, you should use VBA only as a last resort, in case there is no possible excel formula solution.

Comment: totally Agree, but how can formulas merge cells? @Uri Goren